# Backwards translation: “It was you who taught me that peaceful protests are futile.”?

Tags: translation

This recent New York Times article entitled [Hong Kong Has Nothing Left to Lose](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/07/02/opinion/hong-kong-protest.html) mentions, in the opening sentence, that:

> After breaking into Hong Kong’s legislature, protesters left a message for Carrie Lam, the city’s top government official, spray-painted on a pillar: [“It was you who taught me that peaceful protests are futile.”](https://twitter.com/swiftintime/status/1145925863516454914)

The link to the twitter pic has now been protected and is not publicly available.

Any idea what the original text to:

> It was you who taught me that peaceful protests are futile

Is?

I’m assuming it wasn’t English.

---

Found the image later:

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was you who - 是妳

taught me - 教我

peaceful protests - 和平示威

are futile - 是沒用的

[Here is the Chinese version of that article](https://cn.nytimes.com/opinion/20190703/hong-kong-protest/zh-hant/)

> "It was you who taught me that peaceful protests are futile"
>
> "是妳教(識)我和平示威是沒用(的)"

I cannot presume it wasn't originally in English because Hong Kong is an international city, a lot of protest slogans are written in English for foreign news media's view.

*It is an open secret among Chinese that arguing with the CCP government is useless. The protesters have better chance at pulling support from the international community, and the international community would in turn apply pressure to the CCP.*

Comment: Good find. One thing I will say is that the sentence you quoted here is simply just written: `「是你教我和平遊行是沒用。」` while another one mentioned in the article does have English and then a translation in parenthesis: `「If we burn, you burn with us」（要燒死我們，我們同歸於盡）。`

Comment: @user3306356 What amuses me is how they think can burn with (CCP?). They will only burn alone.